# AWS S3 uploadDirectory Drops Connection

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am trying to use the

```
uploadDirectory
```

function of the AWS S3 API for PHP to synchronize a directory of files to my S3 bucket. There's ~4K files in the directory and the total size is about 500GB. Each file is anywhere from between 50 - 150 MB. However, I am randomly and arbitrarily seeing the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Aws\Exception\MultipartUploadException' with message 'An exception occurred while uploading parts to a multipart upload. The following parts had errors:
- Part 5: Error executing "UploadPart" on "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/raw/0234?partNumber=5&uploadId=uploadId"; AWS HTTP error: Error creating resource: [message] fopen(): SSL: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.


[file] C:\php\aws\GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler.php
[line] 312
[message] fopen(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/raw/0234?partNumber=5&uploadId=uploadId): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
[file] C:\php\aws\GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler.php
[line] 312
' in C:\php\aws\Aws\Multipart\AbstractUploadMana in C:\php\aws\Aws\Multipart\AbstractUploadManager.php on line 126


Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\Exception\MultipartUploadException' with message 'An exception occurred while uploading parts to a multipart upload. The following parts had errors:- Part 5: Error executing "UploadPart" on "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/raw/0234?partNumber=5&uploadId=uploadId"; AWS HTTP error: Error creating resource: [message] fopen(): SSL: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
[file] C:\php\aws\GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler.php
[line] 312
[message] fopen(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/raw/0234?partNumber=5&uploadId=uploadId): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
[file] C:\php\aws\GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler.php
[line] 312
' in C:\php\aws\Aws\Multipart\AbstractUploadMana in C:\php\aws\Aws\Multipart\AbstractUploadManager.php on line 126
```

From the error message it seems like AWS is dropping the connection for some reason. Here is the code I'm using

```
$s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
    'http' => [
        'verify' => false
    ],
    'credentials' => CredentialProvider::ini($user_name, $credentials_file_path)
]);


$log_handler = fopen($path_to_log, 'a+');
$s3Client->uploadDirectory($path_to_dir, $bucket, null, array(
   'debug' => $log_handler,
   'concurrency' => 20
));


fclose($log_handler);
```

Setting a lower concurrency seems to allow the process to continue further before the error occurs, but it still seems inevitable. I also found [this article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-multipart-upload.html#recovering-from-errors) which seems to indicate that it's possible to recover from multipart upload errors, but I can't find a way to make it work for this uploadDirectory function.

I am using the latest build of the API, 3.18.32 from 7/21/2016, although before I was working with the version from a month prior and running into the same problem. PHP version is 5.6.22.

Comment: Try Enabling extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini and then see if this happens again?

Comment: @error2007s Oh, I already did that, but I'm still having this problem. It's important to note, I don't think it's an SSL issue, because files DO upload, it's just the overall process fails at some arbitrary point in time.